# Reference books or documents about loading and linking an elf file

Tags: linker, loading, elf

I have implemented some aspects of an elf parser in Windows til getting the symbol table information and the symbol related information. Now I want to go ahead and know more about linking and loading which I believe has to do with parsing the program headers in the elf file.

Till now the elf format specification was very helpful, but I find it difficult to understand and relate to relocation information, linking and loading into virtual memory.

Can anyone suggest a good reference or documents? Is Linkers & Loaders by John R. Levine the book to start with? My requirement is at present limited to elf file formats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linkers & Loaders by John R. Levine is definitely a good resource to get started. It goes into the high level operation of a linker, agnostic to a specific object file format.

However, when it comes down to the nitty gritty details of actually implementing a ELF linker/loader, there really isn't any better documentation than the ELF standard. This is rather unfortunate because the ELF standard is quite terse and can be ambiguous.

Comment: I have been through some of Linkers & Loaders and understood the same.

Comment: @Techiegirl : have you come across any good book on linkers other than by levine as you mentioned above. i have just finished with elf format and want to understand the concept of relocation and linking further. thanks.

Comment: @user1182722 Unfortunately I never came across a better book. Probably looking at the actual code of applications like fromelf may help you. To be frank, the ELF standard is very vague for your purpose.